# pickled python machine learning model uses hardcoded paths, doesn't run on other machine - what to do?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pickle

I use AutoGluon to create ML models locally on my computer.
Now I want to deploy them through AWS, but I realized that all the pickle files created in the process use hardcoded path references to other pickle files:

`/home/myname/Desktop/ETC_PATH/AutoGluon/`

I use `cloudpickle.dump(predictor, open('FINAL_MODEL.pkl', 'wb'))` to pickle the final ensemble model, but AutoGluon creates numerous other pickle files of the individual models, which are then referenced as `/home/myname/Desktop/ETC_PATH/AutoGluon/models/` and `/home/myname/Desktop/ETC_PATH/AutoGluon/models/specific_model/` and so forth...

How can I achieve that all absolute paths everywhere are replaced by relative paths like `root/AutoGluon/WHATEVER_PATH`, where root could be set to anything, depending on where the model is later saved.

Any pointers would be helpful.

**EDIT:** I'm reasonably sure I found the problem. If, instead of loading FINAL_MODEL.pkl (that seems to hardcode paths) I use AutoGluon's `predictor = task.load(model_dir)` it should find all dependencies correctly, whether or not the AutoGluon folder as a whole was moved. [This issue on github helped](https://github.com/awslabs/autogluon/issues/725)

Comment: Move that edit to an answer (if it works), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This solved the problem: If, instead of loading FINAL_MODEL.pkl (that seems to hardcode paths) I use AutoGluon's `predictor = task.load(model_dir)` it should find all dependencies correctly, whether or not the AutoGluon folder as a whole was moved. [This issue on github helped](https://github.com/awslabs/autogluon/issues/725)